# Return NaN for pandas.groupby().sum() of timedelta fields

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, timedelta

When doing a `df.groupby().sum()` in pandas, `nan`s get converted to 0 unexpectedly. This has been noted in this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20824). The ticket suggests that using `groupby().sum(min_count=1)` would correctly return the expected `nan`. Unfortunately it seems to not work for timedeltas (see full working example below).

Are there workarounds on how to keep the nan in a `groupy().sum()` for timedelta fields?

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

data = [[date(year=2020,month=2,day=1), timedelta(hours=1, minutes=10),timedelta(hours=2, minutes=10) ],
    [date(year=2020,month=2,day=2), None,    timedelta(hours=2, minutes=10) ],
    [date(year=2020,month=2,day=3), timedelta(hours=1, minutes=10),timedelta(hours=2, minutes=10) ],
    [date(year=2020,month=2,day=3), timedelta(hours=1, minutes=10),timedelta(hours=2, minutes=10) ]
    ] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'duration', 'total']) 
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']), inplace=True)

res=df.groupby(level=0).sum(min_count=1)
display(res)
```

Expected:

```
date  | duration | total
2020-02-01 | 01:10:00 | 02:10:00
2020-02-02 | NaT | 02:10:00
2020-02-03 | 02:20:00 | 04:20:00
```

But getting

```
date  | duration | total
2020-02-01 | 01:10:00 | 02:10:00
2020-02-02 | 00:00:00| 02:10:00
2020-02-03 | 02:20:00 | 04:20:00
```

Comment: What is your pandas version? For me in `0.25.1` working nice, not sure about `pandas 1.0.1`

Comment: Updated from `0.24.2` to `1.0.1`in the hope of getting this fixed, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, namely to use

`res=df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.sum(min_count=1))`

instead of

`res=df.groupby(level=0).sum(min_count=1)`

Comment: I think `agg` instead of `apply` gives you the same structure of output than your original's one